# Raspberry Pi3 BLE only accepts a single connection

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, raspberry-pi3, bluez

I have created a BLE peripheral that exposes a GATT service. It uses BlueZ 5.50, but it seems that only one device can connect to the GATT service. When the device is connected, then other devices can't see it anymore. It's not showing up in a scan anymore and if it was already scanned, then I can't connect to it anymore.

It seems to be a limitation or configuration issue in BlueZ, because when using the [Paypal GATT](https://github.com/paypal/gatt) library it can handle multiple connections. As far as I know, the RPi3 BLE chip should be able to handle up to 10 connections.

Does anyone know if this can be done using BlueZ?

Comment: I also raised an issue with BlueZ: https://github.com/bluez/bluez/issues/12

Answer (score 0):

The Paypal GATT library directly connects to the HCI device and bypasses most of the kernel stuff. BlueZ depends on kernel drivers and user-space applications and is capable if the driver reports that the controller allows multiple connections. You need a decent BLE controller and a recent kernel to make it work.

More information can be found in https://github.com/bluez/bluez/issues/12.